# Remove order field from Page Attributes box

Tags: wp-admin

I'd like to remove, or at least hide, the Order field from the Page Attributes box. Anyone have a way to go about do this?

[image: order]

Comment: why not to hide it with css?

Answer (score 1):

I went with jQuery to remove the elements.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#pageparentdiv label[for=menu_order]').parents('p').eq(0).remove();
  jQuery('#pageparentdiv input#menu_order').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really just want to hide it from displaying or completely remove it. It’s a part of core Page Attribute Metabox which could'nt be remove permanently 
but this should help get you going in the right direction.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_order_attribution');
function hide_order_attribution() {
         echo '<style>
               label[for="menu_order"],
               input[name="menu_order"] {
                 display:none;
               }
              </style>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer [above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/265647/164213)
But if you wont that it work also with Gutenberg you must to add this selector: `.components-base-control.editor-page-attributes__order`

```
 add_action('admin_head', 'hide_order_attribution');
    function hide_order_attribution() {
             echo '<style>
                   label[for="menu_order"],
                   input[name="menu_order"],
                   .components-base-control.editor-page-attributes__order {
                     display:none;
                   }
                  </style>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If seeking to hide it in the WordPress block editor, the following CSS loaded into the admin works:

```
.editor-page-attributes__order {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm sure there's a more complicated JavaScript approach, but this meets my needs.